# Batch ping remote with condition

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping

I need a windows batch script that will 
1.Ping a remote computer,
     if the remote computer is online
     net use x: \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\remote
     robocopy x c:\remote\
     if remote is offline
try again after 30mins or an hour

Comment: See the "Related" list at the right side below the advertisements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:start
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 3 | findstr "TTL" && call :action
ping localhost -n 1800
goto start

:action
net use x: 
robocopy/xcopy whatever
exit
```